# Merging awk and cut into one command

Tags: bash, awk

My line is:

```
var1="_source.statistics.test1=AAAAA;;;_source.statistics.test2=BBBB;;;_source.statistics.test3=CCCCC"

awk -F  ";;;" '{print $1}' <<<$var1 | cut -d= -f2
AAAAA
awk -F  ";;;" '{print $2}' <<<$var1 | cut -d= -f2
BBBB
```

How can I get to the same result using only AWK?

Comment: `awk -F";;;|=" '{print $2}' <<<$var1` and `awk -F";;;|=" '{print $4}' <<<$var1 ` - you will need to `*2` your field indices. Another, maybe not so efficient way is by using `sub`: `awk -F";;;" '{a=$1; sub(/.*=/, "", a); print a}' <<<$var1`

Comment: Perhaps the question is : what do you want to do with the result ?

Comment: assign to the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, within single `awk` by making use of field separator `-F` setting it as either `=` or `;` for each line passed to `awk`.

```
echo "$var1" | awk -F'=|;' '{print $2}'
AAAAA
echo "$var1" | awk -F'=|;' '{print $6}'
BBBB
```

***OR***

```
echo "$var1" | awk -F"=|;;;" '{print $2}'
AAAAA
echo "$var1" | awk -F"=|;;;" '{print $4}'
BBBB
```

---

---

Considering that you need these output for variables, if yes then you could use it by `sed` and placing its values in an array and later could make use of it. IMHO this is why arrays are built to save our time of creating N numbers of variables.

***Creation of an array with sed:***

```
array=( $(echo "$var1" | sed 's/\([^=]*\)=\([^;]*\)\([^=]*\)=\([^;]*\)\(.*\)/\2 \4/'  ) )
```

***Creating of an array with awk:***

```
array=( $(echo "$var1" | awk -F"=|;;;" '{print $2,$4}') )
```

Above will create an array with values of `AAAAA` and `BBBB` now to fetch it you could use.

```
for i in {0..1}; do echo "$i : ${array[$i]}"; done
0 : AAAAA
1 : BBBB
```

I have used `for` loop for your understanding of it, one could use directly `array[0]` for `AAAAA` or `array[1]` for `BBBB`.

Answer (score 3):

Awk lets you `split` a field on another delimiter.

```
awk -F  ";;;" '{split($1, a, /=/); print a[2] }'
```

However, perhaps a more fruitful approach would be to transform this horribly hostile input format to something a little bit more normal, and take it from there with standard tools.

```
sed 's/;;;/\
/g' inputfile | ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have name/tag=val input data it's useful to create an array of tag-value pairs so you can just print or do whatever else you like with the data by it's tags, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F';;;|=' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["_source.statistics.test1"]}' <<<"$var1"
AAAAA

$ awk -F';;;|=' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f["_source.statistics.test3"], f["_source.statistics.test2"]}' <<<"$var1"
CCCCC BBBB
```